# CollectionViews in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Normally, to obtain the collection view of a control, I will call the following:

```
            CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list.ItemsSource);
```

This is normally done in the code behind of the xaml file.

However, in MVVM, the ViewModel is not supposed to know about the existence of the View. How do I obtain the CollectionView of a control if I want to do it in MVVM fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the CollectionView in the ViewModel

1- You are having the Data Source of your list and you bind the item source of the list with this known Data Source.

2- Suppose DataSource is a DataTable named dt.

```
 CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt); 

 this will give you the CollectionView in ViewModel
```

Comment: For example, if I bind the ItemsSource of my list to SOMEPROPERTY. Then, I can just call (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SOMEPROPERTY)?

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the ItemsSource as a Property in the ViewModel like

```
public CollectionView _sourceForList;
public CollectionView SourceForList
        {
            get
            {
                return _sourceForList;
            }
            set
            {
                _sourceForList = value;
            }
        }
```

then in XAML you can bind this Property to List

```
<ListBox Margin="9,30,9,0" 
         Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceForList}" }/>
```

and you can call like

```
        CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SourceForList);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the CollectionView in the code-behind of the xaml file (View). The MVVM pattern is not about eliminating the code-behind. It's about separation of concerns and testability.

The **BookLibrary** sample of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how to work with the CollectionView for filtering in a MVVM application.